# How to insert configuration in yarn-site.xml in EMR cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, emr

I am have a problem with:

`running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.4 GB physical memory used; 3.4 GB of 6.9 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.`

My cluster is: 4x c3.4xlarge(datanode) and m3.2xlarge(namenode), same my configuration I have only 1.4GB available.

and to resolve this point I Read in this site https://www.knowru.com/blog/first-3-frustrations-you-will-encounter-when-migrating-spark-applications-aws-emr/ and others sites, the point is change the yarn-site.xml and add this config `yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled`

But, when I change this config, save and restart the resourcemanager in EMR, this configuration not applied in configuration page(EMR namenode:8088/conf) and does not work, but config create by default to EMR accept changes.

how can i change my configuration with my cluster EMR running?

I've seen that this setting needs to be configured only in cluster creation, its really?

How can I trick this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was taking this error `running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.4 GB physical memory used; 3.4 GB of 6.9 GB virtual memory used. Killing container` because my spark-driver was going up with default configuration, i put this `--driver-memory 5g`config in my spark-submit jar and solve my problem.

It was only this in my case.